# How to select an element by its attribute when value is an array

Tags: jquery

In HTML:

```
<select name=site[new][fw][version]></select>
```

In jQuery, I've tried:

```
var fwvs=$('select[name=site\\[new]\\[fw]\\[version]]')
```

But fwvs.length return 0. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: nobody cares about valid html?

Comment: @Reigel - Generally, no `:)`. It is common to have `[]` in the `name` attribute - I'm pretty sure PHP *requires* it for multi-value fields to populate its variables correctly. I'm with you if you are referring to the missing quotes though, I added them on my sample.

Comment: this is not valid in HTML5? It was my understanding that attribute values must be enclosed by quotes only if they contain spaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select[name="site[new][fw][version]"]')
```

The attribute selectors can take arguments as strings, wrapped in quotes (single or double, same as JavaScript). Usually these aren't used, but they are useful in this case.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/32SNS/

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski - seems to work well for me, on Firefox, Chrome and IE8.

Comment: That worked! Also, triple escaping (\\\\) worked when double (\\\) failed for me. Double works fine when the array has no other arrays in it, i.e., site[new], but after then, it seems triple escaping must be used. But thanks Kobi, your way worked though! I'll mark it as answered as soon as SO let me do so :)

Comment: @fabjoa - Thanks. The other method should work as well (you are describing a strange error - I'd expect 2 ` \\ ` or 4 ` \\\\ `, if the JS is in a higher-level string), but this is probably simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape both opening (`[`) and closing (`]`) brackets. Check [jquery selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/PL6jE/)

Comment: like : var fwvs=$('select[name=site\\\[new\\\]\\\[fw\\\]\\\[version\\\]]')

Comment: As i commented above, this did not worked for me, I had to use \\\ instead